# Can a simple webpage link contain any virus or do harm to my system?

Tags: malware, virus, drive-by-download

Is there any harm to be expected, if I just clicked on such a link described in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122496/how-are-spammers-using-linkedin-http-linkedin-com-slinkcode-urls/141063#141063)?

Answer (score 0):

A short and obvious answer to your question's header "**Can a simple webpage link contain any virus or do harm to my system**?" is **YES**!
Yes, your system can be easily compromised by exploiting lots of vulnerabilities in various components of the web browser, e.g. plugins.

In addition to this - your details can be collected by the attacker to conduct a recon/scan on the collected IP.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes. When you click a link, your browser does more than just download data from a web site. Images/sounds/videos get uncompressed and displayed, JavaScript/Flash gets executed, browser state data gets modified implicitly or explicitly, and much more. A flaw or oversight in anything that processes, interprets, displays or stores *any* of the data on the page, can cause problems which might be exploitable. All of this takes on a whole new level of worrying when you consider that so much of what you download in the course of loading a web page is either user created, or comes from third parties.