# Spammer using LinkedIn for redirects dangerous or just spam?

Tags: spam, skype

I fell victim to a spam attack as outlined in this other posting [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122496/how-are-spammers-using-linkedin-http-linkedin-com-slinkcode-urls?newreg=4d45a4cf514e4650a0bfe7a109280f6d).

I clicked on the link and was redirected through a bunch of pages. Does someone know whether this is just spam or actually harmful? I am running a full system scan at the moment, not sure whether this is of any use though.

Comment: @zyT I'm stating in the OP that I'm referring to this discussion, however no one is talking about potential malicious software being injected alongside the redirects. (and I can't ask since I don't have commenting rights)

Comment: This question is unanswerable because these kinds of links can be misused by anybody for any purpose. Voting to close as *primarily opnion based*.

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't think I understand. People looked into exactly this case, surely they might be able to say whether this in only spam or more, no? Or at least say something about their impression. Am I on the completely wrong train here?

Comment: The top-voted answer under that question tells you *On the redirected destination this is then checked and used for a further redirect.* So you have no way to know where you are sent to and what the intention of the site is.